# Sympy, How to solve equation with 2 unknowns in given range

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I define two symbols `x` and `y`.

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x', integer=True)
y = sp.symbols('y', integer=True)
```

I know that I can solve equations with one variable as such:

```
expr = 3*x**2 - 12

result = sp.solve(expr, x)
print(result)
```

> [-2, 2]

and I can limit solution range with

```
result = sp.solve([expr, x>0], x)
print(result)
```

> Eq(x, 2)

Now, I want to solve equation with two unknowns in a range of `(0, 10)`. Here is what I tried:

```
expr = 3*x - y - 10
result = sp.solve([expr, x>0, x<10, y>0, y<10], x, y)
```

But it gives NotImplementedError

```
NotImplementedError: 
inequality has more than one symbol of interest.
```

Is it really not implemented or am I doing something wrong? I know sympy is a powerful library so I expect sympy to solve such things. What I expect is the following solutions:

`(x=4, y=2), (x=5, y=5), (x=6, y=8)`

People on the Internet suggests to use `solveset`, `nonlinsolve`, `linsolve` but I couldn't make it work with those methods either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of inequalities in `solve` often confuses users. I think that most users want to use the inequalities to filter the solutions as you say. However `solve` actually expects to use inequalities to simplify an univariate system of inequalities which is something quite different e.g.:

```
In [3]: solve([x**2+1<10, x>2])                                                                                                   
Out[3]: 2 < x ∧ x < 3
```

Note here that solve is returning a `Boolean` result rather than a list of `Expr` which it would normally return. I think that because of this alternate use the `solve` function with a mix of equations and inequalities doesn't quite do what users expect. To show why this can be useful I have actually made use of `solve` like this below.

Your example is really a diophantine problem since the system of equations is underdetermined (1 equation in two unknowns) but you only want integer solutions. I haven't used the diophantine solver myself before but I just had a go and came up with this:

```py
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x, y', integer=True)

eq = 3*x - y - 10
conds = [(0 < x), (x < 10), (0 < y), (y < 10)]

# Solve the diophantine equation for solutions in parameter t_0
t, t_0 = symbols('t, t_0', integer=True)
gensol = diophantine(eq, t, [x, y])
((xs, ys),) = gensol

# "Solve" the inequalities for constraints on t_0
conds_t = [cond.subs(x, xs).subs(y, ys) for cond in conds]
conds_t_sol = solve(conds_t, t_0)

# Find the finite set of values for t_0 and sub in to general solution
set_t0 = (conds_t_sol.as_set() & Integers)
sol_set = [(xs.subs(t_0, ti), ys.subs(t_0, ti)) for ti in set_t0]

print(sol_set)
```

The output is

```
[(4, 2), (5, 5), (6, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach to generating integer solutions to an equation with more than two variables -- the cubic and higher cases are not implemented as diophantine solvers -- is the following (and you would have to filter the solutions once obtained):

```
def make(e, t, quick=True):
    """Return True if t can be made as a linear combination of values in e
    when quick is True, otherwise a list of all multiples of the elements
    needed to make t (with respect to the sorted elements in e).

    Examples
    ========

    >>> make((6, 9, 20), 43)  # c.f. the McNugget problem
    False
    >>> make((6, 9, 20), 50, quick=False)
    [[2, 2, 1], [5, 0, 1]]

    50 can be made as 2*6 + 2*9 + 1*20 or 5*6 + 0*9 + 1*20
    """
    def _(e, t):
        (m, r) = divmod(t, e[0])
        if len(e) == 1:
            if not r:
                yield [t // e[0]]
        else:
            for m in range(m + 1):
                for g in _(e[1:], t - m * e[0]):
                    yield [m] + g

    e = list(sorted([i for i in e if i]))
    if quick:
        for i in _(e, t):
            return True
    else:
        return [i for i in _(e, t)]
```